# Can we make one of the Existing PVOBs a ADMIN VOB?

Tags: clearcase

Our ClearCase structure, as it exists now, has several PVOBs.  But they do not share a ADMIN VOB. Is there a way to make one of them an Admin VOB, so that all the PVOBs can share components?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to:

- create a *new* admin pvob
- link the other pvobs to that new admin pvob (a special hyperlink)

See this [help page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.books.cc_admin.doc/vob-admin.htm).

> Any VOB can be linked to an administrative VOB from which it derives definitions of type objects such as branch types and label types. Type objects are a fundamental part of the Rational ClearCase data model.
>   It is useful to establish an administrative VOB hierarchy into which new VOBs can be placed in order to simplify type administration. For more information about administrative VOBs and global types, see VOB datatypes and administrative VOB hierarchies.
>
> Note:
>   A **PVOB is the administrative VOB for all UCM component VOBs that are included in projects defined in that PVOB**.
>   Every UCM component VOB is created with an AdminVOB hyperlink to its PVOB.
>   If a project uses multiple PVOBs, they must each have an AdminVOB hyperlink to a common PVOB in which shared components and streams are defined.
>   With the VOB Creation Wizard, you can specify the administrative VOB for each new VOB that you create. If you create a VOB with `mkvob`, you must specify the VOB's administrative VOB in a subsequent `mkhlink` command that creates an AdminVOB hyperlink from the VOB to its administrative VOB.

```
cleartool mkhlink -c "link to admin VOB" AdminVOB vob:\dev vob:\admin_dev 
Created hyperlink "AdminVOB@40@\dev".
```

---

Now, the one trick to never forget:

Once you have created your new admin pvob, do not forget to "declare" it (`mktag`) in the region of your VOB server (usually superregion), as well as your local region for your user.
If the vob server does not "see" that pvob tag, no UCM operations will succeed!